# initializing std vector at compile time

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, stdvector

I have the following code running but how do I now initialize a vector or variable with it.

```
constexpr uint32_t _RtlComputeCrc32(
    _In_  DWORD dwInitial,
    _In_reads_bytes_(stLength)    const BYTE *pbyData,
    _In_  INT stLength
)
{
    ULONG crc = 0xFFFFFFFF;

    while (stLength-- != 0)
    {
        pbyData++;
      //  crc = ((crc >> 8) & 0x00FFFFFF) ^ crc32_table[(crc ^ *(pbyData++)) & 0x000000FF];
    }
    return crc ^ 0xFFFFFFFF;
}

constexpr uint32_t crccalc(const std::wstring_view field)
{
    return _RtlComputeCrc32(0, (BYTE*)field.data(), (INT)field.size() * sizeof(wchar_t));
}

template<const wchar_t* T >
struct crcfield
{
    //static constexpr const std::wstring_view  sname = T;
    static constexpr const uint32_t field = crccalc(T);
};

struct Field
{
    std::wstring_view namee;
    static const uint32_t crcfield;
};
```

If I want a static variable now how must this looks like:

```
static constexpr const wchar_t *namee = _T("test");

auto f = crcfield**<???>;**
```

If I for example do the following:

```
 auto f = crcfield<_T("t")>;
```

I get the error:

```
 error C2762: 'crcfield': invalid expression as a template argument for 'T'
```

Comment: And what is the problem with the code you show? What is, indeed, your question? Please read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: A lots of error and the first is: error C3615: constexpr function 'crc' cannot result in a constant expression

Comment: I don't think it's possible: you've declared `crc()` `constexpr` but `crc()` call `crccalc()` that isn't `constexpr` so `crc()` can't be computed compile-time; you can declare `crccalc()` `constexpr`, but `crccalc()` call `RtlComputeCrc32()` that is a function in Win-api. If `RtlComputeCrc32()` isn't `constexpr`, `crccalc()` can't be computed compile-time so also `crc()` can't be computed compile-time. In short: you need a `constexpr` version of `RtlComputeCrc32()`.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. Please also delete your "answers" which do are not answering the question.

Comment: You cannot evaluate `while` loops at compile time. You need to fundamentally rewrite the CRC code for it to be able to run at compile time (you also can’t handle pointers willy-nilly at compile time … you’ll need to use static `char` buffers instead).

Comment: Ok, thank you all.